# Add Numbers in Array Elements

Tags: c++, algorithm

SO i want to write a function to add some numbers

1 ,2, 3, 4, 10, 11

I want to create a Function to add and give 31

Here is the function I created

```
int simpleArraySum(vector<int> ar) {

    int sum =0;
    for (int i = 0; i <11; i++){
        sum += ar[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Does not work as Expected, this does not compile as supposed to. New to this , I need some form of help here.

Fullcode is given as below :

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>

using namespace std;

string ltrim(const string &);
string rtrim(const string &);
vector<string> split(const string &);

/*
 * Complete the 'simpleArraySum' function below.
 *
 * The function is expected to return an INTEGER.
 * The function accepts INTEGER_ARRAY ar as parameter.
 */

int simpleArraySum(vector<int> ar) {

    int sum =0;
    for (int i = 0; i <11; i++){
        sum += ar[i];
    }
    return sum;
}

int main()
{
    ofstream fout(getenv("OUTPUT_PATH"));

    string ar_count_temp;
    getline(cin, ar_count_temp);

    int ar_count = stoi(ltrim(rtrim(ar_count_temp)));

    string ar_temp_temp;
    getline(cin, ar_temp_temp);

    vector<string> ar_temp = split(rtrim(ar_temp_temp));

    vector<int> ar(ar_count);

    for (int i = 0; i < ar_count; i++) {
        int ar_item = stoi(ar_temp[i]);

        ar[i] = ar_item;
    }

    int result = simpleArraySum(ar);

    fout << result << "\n";

    fout.close();

    return 0;
}

string ltrim(const string &str) {
    string s(str);

    s.erase(
        s.begin(),
        find_if(s.begin(), s.end(), not1(ptr_fun<int, int>(isspace)))
    );

    return s;
}

string rtrim(const string &str) {
    string s(str);

    s.erase(
        find_if(s.rbegin(), s.rend(), not1(ptr_fun<int, int>(isspace))).base(),
        s.end()
    );

    return s;
}

vector<string> split(const string &str) {
    vector<string> tokens;

    string::size_type start = 0;
    string::size_type end = 0;

    while ((end = str.find(" ", start)) != string::npos) {
        tokens.push_back(str.substr(start, end - start));

        start = end + 1;
    }

    tokens.push_back(str.substr(start));

    return tokens;
}
```

Comment: Please post the compile errors and create a [mre]

Comment: Avoid magic number such as `i <11`. it should be `ar.size()`.

Comment: `int ar_count = stoi(ltrim(rtrim(ar_count_temp)));` IIRC, `stoi` already skips leading whitespace, so no need to `ltrim`.

Comment: `return std::accumulate(ar.begin(), ar.end(), 0);` - as an unintended consequence, the simplicity calls into question the very need for `simpleArraySum` in the first place.

Comment: what did you expect and what is the code doing instead?

Comment: I guess this is a question from Hacker rank because I can see that only they write such ltrim and rtrim and split functions as template and just ask you to complete the function.

Comment: @risingStark https://www.hackerrank.com/challenges/simple-array-sum/problem. "The function accepts INTEGER_ARRAY ar as parameter." ... d'oh

Comment: `#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;` no and no. P.s. note the existence of `std::accumulate` and `std::reduce`.

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a `vector` as in input in the function, which contains the array elements. Now, the array elements can be anything i.e., integers ranging from `0 < ar[i] <= 1000` as mentioned in the question and you should run a loop till the size of the vector.

```
int simpleArraySum(vector<int> ar) {

    int sum =0;
    for (int i = 0; i < ar.size(); i++){
        sum += ar[i];
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Comment: you could mention `std::accumulate` and that the copy of the vector is 
superfluous

Comment: Yeah, but in hackerrank you are just asked to complete the function and nothing else can't be changed. Moreover, imho it is better to learn about getting size of vector than remember a new in-built function for just one task. But thanks for mentioning.

Comment: _"...the array elements can be anything..."_? Please explain.

Comment: `std::accumulate` is not for just one task. Solving this exercise is just one taks with little benefit for OP beyond that one task, while learning an algorithm will help them in the future. As I understand the hackerrank task, you are allowed to add `const` and `&` to the argument, thats just changes on the function

Comment: anyhow, OP does not mention hackerrank in the question. We should not assume requirements/limitations that are not mentioned in the question (or at least indicate when we do)